# Remove recursively a key from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all `test` keys from an array of objects. So each object that contains `test` should be processed by the function, to remove that key.

```js
const obj = [{
  address: "asda",
  city: "asdasd",
  country: "1",
  description: {
    test: 123,
    name: 'name'
  },
  id: {
    test: 152,
    idB: 'n'
  },
  code: "asdas     ",
  test: 156,
}]

const arr = () => {
  const newKeys = obj.flatMap(item => Object.entries(item))
  const condition = newKeys.filter(i => i[0] !== 'test')
  return Object.fromEntries(condition)
}

console.log(arr())
```

Now i did to remove only the `test` from main object but i can't figure out how to remove each `test` from the rest objects inside main object. How to do this in my code?

Comment: To understand recursion one must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Another option could be to use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) with a replacer function to filter your keys. The replacer is called for each key-value pair as JSON.stringify recursively walks through your array/objects, allowing you to remove key-value pairs by returning `undefined`:

```js
const obj = [{ address: "asda", city: "asdasd", country: "1", description: { test: 123, name: 'name' }, id: { test: 152, idB: 'n' }, code: "asdas     ", test: 156, }];

const removeKey = (obj, keyToRemove) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj,
  (key, val) => key === keyToRemove ? undefined : val)
);

console.log(removeKey(obj, "test"));
```

Please note: This solution assumes your object is stringifiable (for example, doesn't consist of functions), and your keys do not have values of `undefined` (as undefined values are removed from the result).

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869176/use-object-type-output-in-javascript-function?noredirect=1#comment119960796_67869176

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
const obj = [{
  address: "asda",
  city: "asdasd",
  country: "1",
  description: {
    test: 123,
    name: 'name'
  },
  id: {
    test: 152,
    idB: 'n'
  },
  code: "asdas     ",
  test: 156,
}]




function removeTestKey(obj) {
  //check if there are any test property and removes it
  obj.test != undefined ? delete obj.test : null;

  // loop throw the object keys and thier sub objects
  for (let subObj in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[subObj] == "object") {
      removeTestKey(obj[subObj]);
    }
  }
}

obj.forEach(obj => {
  removeTestKey(obj)
})


console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a recursive function that removes the desired key recursively. This recursive function could take in the object and the key to remove as parameters.

Using `Object.keys(...)` method, get an array of the keys of the object passed in as an argument and then using the `reduce()` method, remove the desired key recursively.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    address: 'asda',
    city: 'asdasd',
    country: '1',
    description: {
      test: 123,
      name: 'name',
    },
    id: {
      test: 152,
      idB: 'n',
    },
    code: 'asdas',
    test: 156,
  },
];

function removeKey(obj, keyToRemove) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
    // if the value of the current key is another object,
    // make a recursive call to remove the
    // key from the nested object
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      acc[key] = removeKey(obj[key], keyToRemove);
    }
    // if the current key is not the key that is to be removed,
    // add the current key and its value in the accumulator
    // object
    else if (key !== keyToRemove) {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const removeKeys = (arr, keyToRemovej) => {
  return arr.map(obj => removeKey(obj, keyToRemovej));
};

console.log(removeKeys(obj, "test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and destructure unwanted key and keep the rest.

```js
const
    getValue = (v, fn) => {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) return v.map(fn);
        else if (v && typeof v === 'object') return fn(v);
        return v;                
    },
    remove = key => ({ [key]:_ , ...o }) => Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, getValue(v, remove(key))])
    ),        
    array = [{ address: "asda", city: "asdasd", country: "1", description: { test: 123, name: 'name' }, id: { test: 152, idB: 'n' }, code: "asdas     ", test: 156 }];

console.log(array.map(remove('test')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869176/use-object-type-output-in-javascript-function?noredirect=1#comment119960796_67869176