# Use object type output in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I created this function in my application:

```js
const test = (seconds) => {
  let dateType = "seconds";
  let time = seconds;

  if (seconds % 60 === 0) {
    dateType = "minutes";
    time = seconds / 60;
  }

  if (seconds % 3600 === 0) {
    dateType = "hours";
    time = seconds / 3600;
  }

  if (seconds % 86400 === 0) {
    dateType = "days";
    time = seconds / 86400;
  }

  return {
    dateType,
    time,
  };
};
```

I want to change the function above into something like this:

```js
const test = (seconds) => {
  let dateType = "seconds";
  let time = seconds;

  const OUTPUT = {
    [seconds % 60 === 0]: {
      dateType: "minutes",
      time: seconds / 60,
    },
    [seconds % 3600 === 0]: {
      dateType: "hours",
      time: seconds / 3600,
    },
    [seconds % 86400 === 0]: {
      dateType: "days",
      time: seconds / 86400,
    },
  };

  return OUTPUT[seconds];
};

console.log(test(60)); // here i need to get the first item from OUTPUT
```

How to change the last function, because now i get undefined?

Comment: perhaps the missing `'` in `dateType: 'minutes,` is causing the code to not even parse

Comment: you do realise `[seconds % 86400 === 0]` will be `true` or `false` ... so the object will only ever have at most 2 properties, `true`, and `false` ... and never a numeric property ... like `60` in your example ... add `console.log(OUTPUT);` before you return in that function, and you'll see your problem

Comment: @GalAbra - that too would be undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX, how to change the code to get the expected result?

Comment: Use the function that works, not some arbitrary code that could never work

Comment: @JaromandaX, is there a possibility to fix my last function?

Comment: no, it doesn't work, and the only way I can see to make it work like the first function is to write it like the first function

Answer (score -1):

There is no item in `OUTPUT` with the key `seconds`. The keys of the objects are conditions that become `true` or `false`.

So if you want to get the first item return the item that has the key `'true'` if there is one, else return the item that has the key `'false'`.

**Working example:**

```js
const test = (seconds) => {
  let dateType = "seconds";
  let time = seconds;

  const OUTPUT = {
    [seconds % 60 === 0]: {
      dateType: "minutes",
      time: seconds / 60,
    },
    [seconds % 3600 === 0]: {
      dateType: "hours",
      time: seconds / 3600,
    },
    [seconds % 86400 === 0]: {
      dateType: "days",
      time: seconds / 86400,
    },
  };

  console.log('OUTPUT: ', OUTPUT);
  
  return OUTPUT['true'] ? OUTPUT['true'] : OUTPUT['false'];
};

console.log('60: ', test(60));
console.log('61: ', test(61));
console.log('3600: ', test(3600));
console.log('86400: ', test(86400));
```

Comment: So, what happens when you pass in `61`? hint: it's NOT the same as the first function

Comment: I doubt you'll find code that's very different to the first code in the question - let me rephrase that, of course you can write this in many different ways, some worse than others, I just can't see a significantly better way than the original

Comment: @Asking I updated my answer - please give a feedback...